# Use Spring Aop on Spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I have a Spring MVC controller throw two kind of exception:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "forwardRefundApply",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView forwardRefundApply1(String ticketNbr)throws Exception {
    if(true)
        throw new Exception();
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("test");
}
```

then I write a AOP class to hanlder the Exception then return Model like this:

```
  @Pointcut("execution(public * ..*(..))")
public void getRefundPointCut() {
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut="getRefundPointCut()", throwing="e")
public ModelAndView throwException(Exception e){
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    if(e instanceof ApplicationException)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
        mav = new ModelAndView(CommonConstants.ERRORPAGE);
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", "application error");
        return mav;
    }
    else{
        e.printStackTrace();

        mav  = new ModelAndView(CommonConstants.ERRORPAGE);
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", "system error");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

the aop is work . but the the result is error. system error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

is Aspect class cannot return ModelAndView to Controller?

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

Why use AOP in this case at all? Spring comes with everything you need:

- [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers-resolver) is a global entry point into exception handling.
- [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) lets you define handlers in controllers.
- [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice) lets you define `@ExceptionHandler`s on a global level.

Comment: +1 These are appropriate alternatives for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

The `NoSuchMethodError` is unrelated to your question and is caused by something you haven't shown us.

As for the question

> is Aspect class cannot return ModelAndView to Controller?

I couldn't find any reference to it anywhere in [Spring's AOP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), but you can see it in the implementation.

When you declare a `@AfterThrowing` advice, Spring uses a `AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice` to handle it. Its `invoke(..)` method is implemented as

```
@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return mi.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        if (shouldInvokeOnThrowing(t)) {
            invokeAdviceMethod(getJoinPointMatch(), null, t);
        }
        throw t;
    }
}
```

where `mi.proceed()` invokes your advised method and `invokeAdviceMethod(..)` invokes your `@AfterThrowing` advice method. Notice that it does nothing with the return value. As such, you can return a `ModelAndView` object from a `@AfterThrowing` advice method, but it won't serve any purpose, it'll simply be discarded.

A possible alternative is to declare a `@Around` advice. Within it, you wrap the proceeding call and catch the possible exceptions, handling them appropriately

```
@Around(value = "getRefundPointCut()")
public ModelAndView throwException(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ModelAndView mav = null;
    try {
        return (ModelAndView) joinPoint.proceed(); // might want to make sure that it is a ModelAndView
    } catch(ApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mav = new ModelAndView("home");
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", "application error");
        return mav;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mav = new ModelAndView("home");
        mav.addObject("errorMsg", "system error");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Here you return the value of the advised method if it returns correctly. Or your catch any thrown `Exception` and again handle it appropriately by returning a different `ModelAndView`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself but Spring AOP works with proxy objects and not the actual objects. So e is actually an instance of proxy and not of ApplicationException. So the following condition never executes to true.

```
if(e instanceof ApplicationException)
```

Easiest way of handling this would be to mark your aop setting in Spring configuration file with proxy-target-class="true".

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

HTH